# Tweeting from Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, devise, omniauth

I've set up Devise and Omniauth for users to sign in via email, twitter, and facebook. I'm not trying to allow users to tweet a message from inside the app.

I’ve got it currently working with the following code but it’s only posting from MY twitter account. I’m assuming this has to do with not setting up the Oauth_token correctly. No matter what account logins into the app, it still comes from my account.

In my User model, I have the following code (I’ve changed my key and tokens)…

```
def self.find_for_twitter_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
      user = User.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
      if user
        return user
      else
        registered_user = User.where(:email => auth.uid + "@twitter.com").first
        if registered_user
          return registered_user
        else

          user = User.create(full_name:auth.extra.raw_info.name,
                              provider:auth.provider,
                              uid:auth.uid,
                              email:auth.uid+"@twitter.com",
                              oauth_token:auth.credentials.token,
                              oauth_secret:auth.credentials.secret,
                              password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20],
                            )
        end

      end
    end

    def tweet(tweet)
      client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
        config.consumer_key        = "XXXXXXXX"
        config.consumer_secret     = "XXXXXXX"
        config.access_token        = "XXXXXXX-XXXXX"
        config.access_token_secret = "XXXXXXX"
      end

      client.update(tweet)
    end
```

In my config/initializer/devise.rb I have the following:

```
# Add Twitter OmniAuth
  require 'omniauth-twitter'
  config.omniauth :twitter, ENV['TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY'], ENV['TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET']
  # Add Facebook OmniAuth
  require 'omniauth-facebook'
  config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'], :scope => 'basic_info, email, publish_stream'
```

In my view, I'm using a form for them to fill out and submit the tweet.

```
<p>
  <%= form_for :tweet, url: tweets_path, method: :post do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :message %>
    <%= f.submit "Send Tweet" %>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should authorize each twitter user with your app (as I remember with consumer key and consumer secret only).

I did this with simple way:

```
consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new($TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, $TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET, :site => "https://api.twitter.com")
request_token = consumer.get_request_token(:oauth_callback => "http://localhost/twitter/auth_callback")
return request_token.authorize_url
```

by URL I have

```
access_token = request_token.get_access_token(:oauth_verifier => params[:oauth_verifier] )
token = access_token.token
secret = access_token.secret
```

Now if you set these toekn and secret in to your REST client you can post tweets from your user account.